# Entity Framework with oracle can´t change connection string

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework, connection-string

I´m using Entity Framework (latest Version) with the Oracle Driver (latest Version) in an ASP.NET MVC 5 Application. I want to set the connection string for my model during runtime, but every time I do it receives the data from the table that I used to create the model. It´s the same when I change the connection string in the web.config. Does anybody know why it behaves this way?

this is how i create the connection string:

```
    public static string CreateConnectionString(string userName, string service)
    {
        const string providerName = "Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client";

        OracleConnectionStringBuilder oraBuilder = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder();
        oraBuilder.DataSource = service + ":1521/" + service;
        oraBuilder.UserID = userName;
        oraBuilder.Password ="xxx";
        oraBuilder.PersistSecurityInfo = true;

        EntityConnectionStringBuilder efBuilder = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder();
        efBuilder.Metadata = "res://*/Model2.csdl|res://*/Model2.ssdl|res://*/Model2.msl";
        efBuilder.Provider = providerName;
        efBuilder.ProviderConnectionString = oraBuilder.ConnectionString;
        return efBuilder.ConnectionString;
    }
```

this is the overload of the model´s constructor:

public Entities(string connectionString)
            : base(connectionString)
        {

```
    }
```

this ist my connection string:

Comment: Please post some example code for your context.

Comment: this ist my connection string:
<add name="Entities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model2.csdl|res://*/Model2.ssdl|res://*/Model2.msl;provider=Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ent2.tmsent:1521/ent2.tmsent;password=xxx;persist security info=True;user id=TMSENT2&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />

Answer (score 0):

```
     try this connection string:        
     <connectionStrings>
<add name="VoccDbContext" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Entities.Vocc.VoccModel.csdl|res://*/Entities.Vocc.VoccModel.ssdl|&#xD;&#xA;res://*/Entities.Vocc.VoccModel.msl;provider=Oracle.DataAccess.Client;provider connection string=&quot;DATA SOURCE=sameDbName;PASSWORD=somePass;USER ID=someUser;&quot;"providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
     </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: this looks similar to my connection string?

Comment: check your ManagedDataAccess in  oracle client

Comment: if i use  your connectionstring i´ll get an exception wich says it cannot cast ...DataAccess... to ManagedDataAccess

Answer (score 0):

```
DIRECTORY_SERVERS=(tnsnames.somesite.org:389:636)
DEFAULT_ADMIN_CONTEXT="dc=site,dc=com"
DIRECTORY_SERVER_TYPE=OID

here( LDAP.ORA file) to be modified with correct LDAP Parameters
```

Comment: what do you mean by this?

Comment: Explaining your code would help make this a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

Do not edit `XXXModels.cs`. Try to edit `XXXModels.Context.tt`.

Add following code after `public <#=code.Escape(container)#>()...}`

```
public <#=code.Escape(container)#>(string connectionString)
        : base(connectionString)
    {
<#
if (!loader.IsLazyLoadingEnabled(container))
{
#>
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
<#
}

foreach (var entitySet in container.BaseEntitySets.OfType<EntitySet>())
{
    // Note: the DbSet members are defined below such that the getter and
    // setter always have the same accessibility as the DbSet definition
    if (Accessibility.ForReadOnlyProperty(entitySet) != "public")
    {
#>
        <#=codeStringGenerator.DbSetInitializer(entitySet)#>
<#
    }
}
#>
    }
```